# Using a .pem file private key to sign a string with RSASSA-PSS in Go

Tags: go, rsa, private-key, sign, pem

I'm trying to set up Amazon Pay, and following their guide for signing requests:
https://amazonpaycheckoutintegrationguide.s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-pay-api-v2/signing-requests.html

I'm stuck on Step 3. I have a .pem file from Amazon containing a private key. It looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
M...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm supposed to sign a string I created earlier using the RSASSA-PSS algorithm with SHA256 hashing and a salt length of 20. I see that Go has a function to do so (https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPSS), but I'm not sure how to take my .pem file private key and use it in this function. It wants an *rsa.PrivateKey by the looks of it...

I've tried this...

```
var privateKeyString = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...`
decoded, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(privateKeyString))
parsed, _ := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(decoded.Bytes)
privateKey := parsed.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
```

But pem.Decode is returning nil. I've also tried:

```
parsed, _ := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey([]byte(privateKeyString))
```

But this returns nil as well. I'm not familiar with crypto type stuff at all, so if anybody could provide some guidance it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode was returning nil because of how the private key string in back ticks was auto-indented! Removing all the indentation fixed the issue.

Comment: I'd speculate your crucial problem is ignoring errors: _never_ do something like `decoded, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(privateKeyString))` in Go: Go (luckily) has not exceptions so if `pem.Decode` here fails to decode the string, it returns _something_ (usually the so-called zero-value for the type of its "normal" return value), and a non-`nil` error, which you did not check. Never assume somthing is definitely OK. If you cannot bear `if err != nil` blocks, write helpers like [this one](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Must).

Comment: You're absolutely right that I should be checking for errors, and I didn't do it for the parse call in this case! But, I think Decode doesn't actually return an error, as the second return is just for the rest of the input that wasn't part of the first found PEM formatted block. In my case, it would have just been the entire input since no PEM formatted blocks were found.

Comment: OK, consider accepting your own answer ;-) It's perfectly OK as per SO rules.